# Else-part of code being executed, even if string.equals(otherstring) is true

Tags: try-catch, equals, if-statement, finally

The problem with this code seems to be that the 'else' part of the if-statement is executed, even if the variables match (so 'if' is true). Any advice, please?

Thanks!

```
    public void CheckInstalledDBVersion() throws NullPointerException, IOException {

    try {

                  //TRY TO OPEN DATABASE AND READ VERSION
                  //WRITE VERSION TO InstalledDBversion

    } catch(RuntimeException e) {

                  //IF TABLE COULD NOT BE QUERIED
                  //SET InstalledDBversion to Bogus value

        InstalledDBversion = "00";
        Log.d("RTE", ".. but we've catched it!");

    } finally {
        if (InstalledDBversion.equals(PackedDBversion)){

            // Installed DBVersion == Packed DBVersion .. nothing happens

        }
        else

                showDialog(DBCHECKFAILDIALOG);
            initialiseDatabase = false;
            copyDB();
        }
    }
```

So, when I execute, `copyDB();` gets called even if `InstalledDBversion.equals(PackedDBversion) == true`

Comment: InstalledDBversion.equals(PackedDBversion) is not returning what you think it is. To find out what this value truly holds place a breakpoint at this line and check the locals to see what this value holds. Is it a bool? If so what value is it returning? If it's not returning what you're expecting then your logic is wrong somewhere..

Comment: Have you checked the spellings of every word in if (condition) part ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
else
   showDialog(DBCHECKFAILDIALOG);

initialiseDatabase = false;
copyDB();
```

Fixed indentation for you. `copyDB` is outside of the `if/then/else` block. Use an IDE with code formatting.

Comment: Ahhhh! I see.. I'm missing the {} .. Stupid, dumbdumb.. *ooof*

Answer (score 0):

What lines are supposed to be included in the else block? the `showDialog(DBCHECKFAILDIALOG)` is only included. Are you missing a set of `{}` for the else block?

Comment: Ahhhh! I see.. I'm missing the {} .. Stupid, dumbdumb.. ooof